# Git ignores directory that is not in .gitignore, exclude or config file

Tags: android, git, android-studio, git-bash, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a directory in my project that is being ignored but it is not in any of the places that I would expect ignored folders to be (.gitignore, exclude or config).

it is an Android Studio project that I build with gradle, my VCS is Git.
I'm using SourceTree & GitBash to manage the repo.
I've reset all .ignore files in my project to be empty, \info\exclude is empty and config doesn't have 'excludesfile' property.

folder being ignored is - 'myProj/app/src/debug/res/raw/'
have no idea how this folder got ignored in the first place.
there is a different relative folder 'myProj/app/src/debug/res/values' that is tracked by git.

Is there any other place I didn't look that set ignore files?
Is there any git command that can show where is this folder being set as ignored folder?
maybe a binary I overlooked that I can just delete?

currently running 'git status --ignored' show only 'myProj/app/src/debug/res/raw/' as ignored.

Comment: File is called `.gitignore`. Are you sure you look into right place?

Comment: Note that a gitignore may be present in any directory, and not just the parent directory, so check for all files named `.gitignore` within your repo.

Comment: Just to be sure that you don't have a global gitignore file: does `git config --get core.excludesfile` return anything?

Comment: thanks Alexey, I meant .gitignore of course, I've edit the title.

Comment: I just ran into this same issue - build/ wasn't in any ignore or my core.excludesfile! The `add -f` solution worked, but I'm still bewildered as to how this came about

Answer (score 18):

Use `git check-ignore -v myProj/app/src/debug/res/raw/` to see where the ignore is. You may have to give it the name of a file in that directory instead of the directory itself.

Comment: Thanks! Interestingly, there was another gitignore that it was looking at (setup by `GitHub for Mac`!). It was in `~/.config/git/ignore`. I used @Alan's solution to force it

Answer (score 4):

Thanks guys for responding so quick,

I've eventually resolved the issue by just adding the folder using:

- git add -f myProj/app/src/debug/res/raw/

then commit and push, this was suppose to be a meanwhile solution until real solution is found but did the trick, after doing that the folder started to be tracked.

Comment: "after doing that the folder started to be tracked", well it would be. Git's ignore system only applies to files that aren't tracked. By using `git add -f` you told Git to start tracking that content, so any ignore rules on that content no longer apply. You probably still have an errant rule, though.

Comment: This resolved it for me too, and there are no errant rules. A global search of the entire repo brings up nothing. And a `git check-ignore` doesn't show it as being in a .gitignore. This only occurs if I add an empty folder, and later add files to it.

Answer (score 3):

Note that your rule may also exist in the `.gitignore_global` file (in your user folder). You may have accidentally added it by choosing "Global ignore list" in the "Add this ignore entry to" dropdown in SourceTree.

[image: Don't do this!]

*You usually don't want to add a folder name to your global ignore list*

Comment: Git doesn't have a global ignore by default. This is configured using the `core.excludesfile` option. SourceTree might enable this option for you.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is 5 years old but it's the first one on Google results.

Another possibility besides the ones mentioned before is that the folder has been added as a submodule. E.g. in GitHub, the bottom folder is a submodule:

[image: Example]

This happened to me recently while copying a whole git project into another. That is, my repo looked like this:

```
repo
|
|__ .gitignore
|__ .git/ #git folder for repo
|__ some_files.ext
|
|__ ignored_folder
     |__ .git/ #git folder of the copied repo
     |__ .gitignore
     |__ some_other_files.ext
```

My specific solution was to:

1. Cut the whole `ignored_folder` outside of the repo.
2. Add&commit to delete the submodule in the repo
3. Delete the `.git` folder inside the moved `ignored_folder`.
4. Move the `ignored_folder` back in.
5. Add&commit.

However, I'm sure there are [much better *git-like* solutions](https://gist.github.com/kyleturner/1563153).

Comment: I made the same mistake, and this fix worked for me. There was no .submodules file that I could find, nor was the folder in question listed in `.git/config`. But the copy-push-paste-push approach fixed it.

Comment: deleting the `.git` folder inside the ignored folder is really all you need to do.